# Atualizar div com o valor do checkbox marcado

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho esses checkbox na minha página

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dezenas[]" value="01" />
<input type="checkbox" name="dezenas[]" value="02" />
<input type="checkbox" name="dezenas[]" value="03" />
<input type="checkbox" name="dezenas[]" value="04" />
```

To precisando de uma função pra atualizar uma div imprimindo os valores dos checkbox marcados sem refresh na página. É necessário que a div seja atualizada também quando o checkbox for desmarcado, apagando o valor na div.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se pretende que a div seja atualizada quando marca e desmarca as checkbox's precisa de utilizar o evento `change`. Nesse evento tem de percorrer todos os `<input>` e colocar o seu valor se o atributo `checked` estiver a `true`.

Exemplo:

```js
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll("input[name='dezenas[]']")];
const res = document.getElementById("resultado");

inputs.forEach(x => x.addEventListener("change", ()=> {
  //esta função corre quando houve alteração de um dos checkboxes
  res.innerHTML = ""; //limpar o resultado

  //passar em todos os inputs e adicionar o seu value e <br> se tiver checked
  inputs.forEach (y => res.innerHTML += y.checked ? y.value + "<br>" : "");
}));
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="dezenas[]" value="01" />
<input type="checkbox" name="dezenas[]" value="02" />
<input type="checkbox" name="dezenas[]" value="03" />
<input type="checkbox" name="dezenas[]" value="04" />

<div id="resultado"></div>
```

[Documentação para o evento change no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

Comment: Muito Obrigado Isac.

Comment: @BrunoOliveira De nada, fico contente por ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Com jquery:

```
$( "input:checkbox" ).on('click', function() { // evento click para inputs checkbox
$('#myDivId').html(''); // limpa div
$( "input:checkbox" ).each(function () { // percorrer inputs checkbox
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { // se checked
        $('#myDivId').append($(this).val()); // adiciona valor a div
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que o seu código está fazendo pra ajudar a compreensão?

Comment: Alterado com explicação, peço desculpa se percebi mal e não é o que pretende.