# Como posso pegar cada checkbox selecionado e colocar dentro de um input?

Tags: javascript

Possuo alguns checkbox e quero que, ao clicar em um botão, todos os nomes destes selecionados, irem para um input separados por ",".

Tentei fazer desta forma, mas não deu certo:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbx-1">
<input type="checkbox" name="cbx-2">
<input type="checkbox" name="cbx-3">

<input type="text" id="text">

<button type="button" id="bt-ok">Ok</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#bt-ok').click(function() {
    $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function(){
        $("#text").val($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Exemplo no [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0byLz7x/).

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Atualizar div com o valor do checkbox marcado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252170/atualizar-div-com-o-valor-do-checkbox-marcado)

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino pode ser possível duplicata, mas, como você pode ver no meu exemplo, não está funcionando. Inclusive utilizo o mesmo recurso que foi apresentado nesse link que enviou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aproveitando o que estavas a fazer, podes fazer o seguinte:

```js
var vals;
$('#bt-ok').click(function() {
    vals = [];
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
        vals.push($(this).prop('name'));
    });
    $("#text").val(vals.join(', '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="cbx-1">
<input type="checkbox" name="cbx-2">
<input type="checkbox" name="cbx-3">

<input type="text" id="text">

<button type="button" id="bt-ok">Ok</button>
```

Comment: Perfeito @Miguel. Só uma pergunta, porque não poderia ser declarado `var vals = [];`? Seria por alguma prática de boa programação?

Comment: @jsnow porque queremos delegar um array vazio a cada click do btn, caso contrário ficaria buggado se clicasses mais do que uma vez: https://jsfiddle.net/4xafkufd/, se não declararmos a varíavel vazia vai continuar a ser populada, aí não faz sentido

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#bt-ok').click(function() {
  $("#text").val('');
  $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
    //cbx_selecionados.push($(this).val());
    $("#text").val($("#text").val() + $(this).attr('name') + ', ');
  });
});
```

Comment: Valeu, funcionou também. Mas só um detalhe: quando se tem apenas um checkbox marcado, ele adiciona a vírgula, também.

Comment: Era só um exemplo, ia melhorar agora com mais tempo, mas a resposta do @Miguel esclarece melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não percebi qual é o conteudo que desejas por mas o teu select "[name=type]" não faz qualquer sentido.
Penso que é este o teu objectivo!

```
$('#bt-ok').click(function() {
    var temp;
    $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
        //cbx_selecionados.push($(this).val());
    console.log(this);
    temp +=$(this).val()+",";

    });
    temp = temp.slice(0, -1);
    $("#text").val(temp);
});
```